# How can i print specific values from an ArrayList given another Arraylist?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, java.util.scanner, contains

I wish to print out data from an `ArrayList` based on another `ArrayList`.

So I have 3 ArrayLists.

The `IdNumber`, which contains all the ID's of interest for me.

```
ArrayList<String> IdNumber = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h];
```

Then I have 2 ArrayLists which are created like this, by Scanning CSV files:

```
public String toString() {
    return "User [Id_number = " + Id_Number + " ,Information 2 = " + smth2 + ",Information 3 = " + smth3 +"] " + newLine;
}
```

The result output of `System.out.println(ArrayListONE)` will look like this:

```
   User [Id_number = a ,Information 2 = smth2,Information 3 = smth3] 
   User [Id_number = b ,Information 2 = smth2,Information 3 = smth3] 
   User [Id_number = c ,Information 2 = smth2,Information 3 = smth3]
```

This list will contain every row&column from the csv whish is of interest to me.

What I wish to achieve is

```
if(ArrayListOne.contains(IdNumber)){

  // Print out 
  // User [Id_number = a ,Information 2 = smth2,Information 3 = smth3] from that list which contains the given Id_number
```

Any advice?
 I have tire `.equals()` and also `.contains()`

I have considered using `HasMap` for this purpose, but I'm more familiar with ArrayLists. The end result will hopefully use an SQLite connection to a DB.

Comment: If you read the **type** of the lists, it would be much easier to understand. Your list of IDs is a List<String>. So what it contains is objects of type String. Calling contains(foo) on that list can only return true if foo is a String. Your second list is, presumably, of type List<User>. So it contains objects of type User. Calling contains(foo) on that list can only return true if foo is a User. A String can't be contained in a List<String>, just like an egg box can conain eggs, but not cars.

Comment: You need to iterate over all the users of the List<User>, and test if one of them has an ID (of type String) contained in the list of IDs (of type List<String>).